# Disadvantage of holding an activity context reference in a fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

In my fragments I am doing this to get hole a reference to a Context:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.context = activity;
}
```

Could that be a problem? Is it a window to memory leaks?
if so, What is the better way?
(using `getActivity()` can some times return null and can create problems)

Comment: but why to hold to reference for Context globally? you can call getActivity() where ever you need Context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It't not a problem, but to be sure set it to null in [onDestroyView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDestroyView%28%29)

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
    super.onDestroyView();
    context = null;
}
```

Comment: As long as you don't make that context variable static it shouldn't leak. When the fragment is detached it will go out of scope and will be collected by the gc. But I would set it to null just to be sure. The fragment already keeps a reference to the activity that created it that can be retrieved with getActivity().